# How can you run a PHP file without opening a web browser from a C# program?

Tags: c#, process.start

I am writing a tool which will allow users to communicate with each other over the internet using a server and PHP files that I have set up. I have written it, but right now when I open the PHP files and pass arguments through the URL to create new files on my server, it opens the PHP file in my default browser. This is the code I am using right now to open the PHP files on my server:

```
private void ExecuteProcess(string FilePath)
{
    Process Process = new Process();
    Process.StartInfo.FileName = @FilePath;
    Process.Start();
}
```

I want to be able to open files in a similar way without physically opening them in my browser. I have been googling around for a few hours, but whenever I try to user the methods that I find on the internet I get a 406 exception from Visual Studio, saying that the server cannot fufill my request? My write permissions are set to read for these files, do I need to change these?
Thanks for helping a PHP noobie,
-I

Comment: This is actually just a C# question, so the unrelated tags have been removed

Comment: The process you want to start is a web browser, not the php file itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to make an HTTP request to your server. Check the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks, I have already used the method for reading files from my ftp server, so I will just download the PHP file with it. Would this work for executing it? Would it also download whatever text is written while the file is run?

Comment: The PHP code would be executed on the remote server.  It's a standard web request.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and then comment on how it went.

Answer (score 0):

When i used the web request class, there was a page 406 error, which meant that the servers acceptable headers were not comparable with the type of data I was requesting. By default, mod security is turned on on apache servers, and I just need to disable it to allow me to download data with the web request class.unfortunately, the server is hosted by a third party, so I will have to contact the web master in order to turn this off. I have opted just to host my own server, and avoid this hassle.